# Uploading Image from android to PHP server

Tags: php, android, image-uploading

In my app i am uploading an image from my device to a local web server...
after executing the code a .jpg file gets created in the server but it does not gets opened.
And the size of the file in server is different from the original file.

**Android activity:--**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnSelectImage=(Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    btnSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i=new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null) {

        Uri selectedImage=data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

        ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBox);
        im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        /*
         * Convert the image to a string
         * */
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
        byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr,Base64.DEFAULT);

        /*
         * Create a name value pair for the image string to be passed to the server
         * */
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();            
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));


        JSONObject jsonString=new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonString.put("img", image_str);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new uploadImageToPhp().execute(jsonString);



    }


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


    return true;
}
public class uploadImageToPhp extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Void>
{
    String dataToSend=null;

    public static final String prefix="http://";                                                        //prefix of the urls
    public static final String server_ip="172.16.26.155";                                                   //the ip address where the php server is located    

    public static final String completeServerAddress=prefix+server_ip+"/test_upload/upload_image.php";                  //Exact location of the php files

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {

        dataToSend="image="+params[0];
        communicator(completeServerAddress, dataToSend);




        return null;
    }

    public void communicator(String urlString,String dataToSend2)
    {
        String result=null;

        try
        {
            URL url=new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();

            HttpURLConnection httpConn=(HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", "UTF-8");
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");         
            httpConn.connect();

            //Create an output stream to send data to the server
            OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream());
            out.write(dataToSend2);
            out.flush();

            int httpStatus = httpConn.getResponseCode();            
            System.out.println("Http status :"+httpStatus);

            if(httpStatus==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                Log.d("HTTP STatus", "http connection successful");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                    sb.append(inputLine+"\n");
                }
                in.close();
                result=sb.toString();                       

                try
                {

                    //jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                     Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }


            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Somthing went wrong");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}

}
```

**PHP code:-**

```
 $recievedJson=$_REQUEST['image'];
$imageContent=json_decode($recievedJson,true);
 $base=$imageContent["img"];

 $binary=base64_decode($base);

 echo $binary;
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use below code. It will do the same.

```
public class UploadImage extends Activity {
    InputStream inputStream;
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));

             Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                  try{
                         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("server-link/folder-name/upload_image.php");
                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                         String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "Response " + the_string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                          
                                }
                            });

                     }catch(Exception e){
                          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                              
                            }
                        });
                           System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                     }  
            }
        });
         t.start();
        }

        public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{

             String res = "";
             StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
             inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
             int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); //getting content length…..
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "contentLength : " + contentLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                     
            }
        });

             if (contentLength < 0){
             }
             else{
                    byte[] data = new byte[512];
                    int len = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
                        {
                            buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); //converting to string and appending  to stringbuffer…..
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        inputStream.close(); // closing the stream…..
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    res = buffer.toString();     // converting stringbuffer to string…..

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "Result : " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                    //System.out.println("Response => " +  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
             }
             return res;
        }
}
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
     $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    $file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……';
?>
```

**UPDATE**

NameValuePair and Http Classes are deprecated so, I've tried this code and it's working for me. Hope that helps!

```
private void uploadImage(Bitmap imageBitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
    byte[] b = stream.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> params = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
    params.add(new Pair<>("image", encodedImage));

    try {
        new AsyncUploader().execute(my_upload_php, getQuery(params));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getQuery(List<Pair<String, String>> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for(Pair<String, String> pair : params){
        if(first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.first, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.second, "UTF-8"));
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private class AsyncUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String urlString = strings[0];
        String params = strings[1];
        URL url = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(params);
            wr.flush();

            stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            String result = reader.readLine();
            return result;
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected  void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(MakePhoto.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using httpurlconnection for all other communication , so I was thinking to use the same for uploading the images ,

Comment: But this is more easiest way to upload image and this code is perfectly working for me.

Comment: httpClient is depreciated now so this answer is kind of useless unless you do stuff to get httplclient the other way ;)

Comment: BaseNameValuePair is deprecated. Update a new method.

Comment: `String ba1= Base64.encodeToString(imagearray1, Base64.DEFAULT);`

Comment: which methods are outdated?

Comment: why use BasicNameValuePair over hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrlPost(String url, String userid,
                String filepath, String status) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            HttpParams httpParams = httpclient.getParams();
            httpParams.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 100000);
            try {
                entity.addPart("id",
                        new StringBody(userid, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                entity.addPart("sharestatus",
                        new StringBody(status, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(filepath)));
                httppost.setEntity(entity);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                return new JSONObject(response.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }



------------------------------------------------------------------
in main.java  



JSONParser js = new JSONParser();
String url="";// upload file with Server url
            JSONObject data = js.getJSONFromUrlPost(url);
            String response;
            try {
                response = data.getString("Msg");
                if (response.contains("Succesfully upload file")) {
                    JSONObject jsondata = new JSONObject(data.getString("Data"));
                    Fileurl = jsondata.getString("Url");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```