# Image to Base64 conversion issue

Tags: android

I am creating demo app for Image to base64 conversion.Some of the image converting base64 properly. When Image Size is 3.92Mb(4128*3096) and convert to base64 created successfully and upload to server but not uploaded .
After Base64 String write in file and  text file size is 5.40Mb.

Below Code For Image Convet to base64

```
public String convertImage(File file)  {

    FileInputStream inputSteam = new FileInputStream(file);
    inputSteam.read(getBytesFromFile(file));

    return Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromFile(file, Base64.DEFAULT);
}


public byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    // Get the size of the file
    long length = file.length();

    // You cannot create an array using a long type.
    // It needs to be an int type.
    // Before converting to an int type, check
    // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {

        // File is too large
    }

    // Create the byte array to hold the data
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

    // Read in the bytes
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
    if (offset < bytes.length) {

        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+ file.getName());
    }

    // Close the input stream and return bytes
    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

How to handle this issue. Or any other way to convert image;

Answer (score 0):

if you use PHP as a server, did you check max size of upload file in PHP.ini

Answer (score 0):

base64 string file should be larger then original file size because base64 encoding add its own character in string for maintain base64 format. so may be this is the issue for larger file size then original size.

Comment: Any other solution for handling image

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306720/uploading-image-from-android-to-php-server) pls see this link may be it will help you.