# Upload files from android works in emulator, but not in actual phone

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to pass users data (ex: name, phone, email), and file attachment from android, to php server and data will be saved in mysql. When I run using emulator, data is inserted successfully (using multipartEntity), however using actual phone, it's giving error as if the parameter is not stated.

in NextActivity.java:

```
private class RegisterPSJobActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        // private void registerPSJob(){

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            String svcCtr = spinnerSvc.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String product = spinnerProduct.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String name = (String) arg0[0];
            String phone = (String) arg0[1];
            String email = (String) arg0[2];
            String imei = (String) arg0[3];
            String username = (String) arg0[4];

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            String dateNow = dateFormat.format(date);

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                /*
                 * HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                 * "http://192.168.43.140/ps/sendJobs.php");
                 */
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        URL + "sendJobs.php");

                MultipartEntity mEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,null,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                mEntity.addPart("dealer", new StringBody(dealer));
                mEntity.addPart("svcCtr", new StringBody(svcCtr));
                mEntity.addPart("product", new StringBody(product));
                mEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody(name));
                mEntity.addPart("phone", new StringBody(phone));
                mEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody(email));
                mEntity.addPart("imei", new StringBody(imei));
                mEntity.addPart("date", new StringBody(dateNow));
                mEntity.addPart("createdBy", new StringBody(username));
                mEntity.addPart("timeUpdated", new StringBody(dateNow));

                // Thread.sleep(1000);
                //System.out.println(fileUri.getPath());
                mEntity.addPart("attach1", new FileBody(new File(fileUri.getPath()), "application/octet-stream","UTF-8"));
                mEntity.addPart("attach2",new FileBody(new File(fileUriPOD.getPath()), "application/octet-stream","UTF-8"));

                httppost.setEntity(mEntity);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Fail 1", ex.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            try {


                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line = null;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");

                }
                reader.close();
                is.close();

                result = sb.toString();
                Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
            } catch (Exception ex1) {
                Log.e("Fail 2", ex1.toString());
            }

            try {
                Log.i("Info", result);
                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                code = (json_data.getInt("code"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            }
            return Integer.toString(code);
        }
```

SendJobs.php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","psapp");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$imei = $_POST['imei'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$target_path = "upload/";
$target_path2 = "upload/";
$copy_path = "D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/PS/upload/";
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'ps' . '/' . $target_path;

if (isset($_FILES['attach1']['name']) && isset($_FILES['attach2']['name'])) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['attach1']['name']);
    $target_path2 = $target_path2 . basename($_FILES['attach2']['name']);
}

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attach1']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    // make error flag true
    echo true;
    echo 'Could not move the file!';
}
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attach2']['tmp_name'], $target_path2)) {
    // make error flag true
    echo true;
    echo 'Could not move the file!';
}
copy('C:/wamp/www/ps/upload/'.$_FILES['attach1']['name'],$copy_path.$_FILES['attach1']['name']);
copy('C:/wamp/www/ps/upload/'.$_FILES['attach2']['name'],$copy_path.$_FILES['attach2']['name']);

$attach1 = $_FILES['attach1']['name'];
$attach2 = $_FILES['attach2']['name'];

$dateNow = $_POST['date'];
$timeUpdated = $_POST['timeUpdated'];
$createdBy = $_POST['createdBy'];
$dealerLocation = $_POST['dealer'];
$sc = $_POST['svcCtr'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
$randomNo = rand();

$flag['code']=0;
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
if($result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO PSJOB (DEALERLOCATION, SERVICEORDER, SERVICECENTER, PRODUCT, IMEINO, NAME, PHONE, EMAIL, ATTACHMENT1, ATTACHMENT2, REGISTRATIONDATETIME, CREATEDBY, TIMEUPDATED, STATUS) 
VALUES('$dealerLocation', '$randomNo', '$sc', '$product', '$imei', '$name', '$phone', '$email', '$attach1', '$attach2', '$dateNow', '$createdBy', '$timeUpdated', 'REGISTRATION')")){
    $flag['code']=1;
    #echo"hi";
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysqli_close($con);
```

Error msg: (as if the php code cannot find name, imei, or rest of parameter)
undefined index name in sendJobs line ...
undefined index imei in sendJobs line ...

Comment: When i test my App on real devices, i can't use wamp server localhost, folder C:/wamp/www/ps/upload/, D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/PS/upload/ etc Real device do not see these resources.

Comment: I removed the two lines copy, but still shows below messages : <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: imei in C:\wamp\www\ps\sendJobs.php on line <i>8</i></th></tr>  <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\ps\sendJobs.php on line <i>9</i></th></tr>

Comment: I saw this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306720/uploading-image-from-android-to-php-server

Tried to use in my code and it works.