# Background Task for multiple operations- Android

Tags: android, mysql, bitmap, background-task

I am inserting multiple fields into MySQL DB using PHP as webservice, Android Studio 2.1.2, testing on a physiacal device(Android 4.4.2). I have a background task for DB interaction. I dont want the next Activity to show up until all of the DB entries have been made. Is there some code to use in onPostExucte(),or perhaps anywhere else, that would open Activity ONLY after inserting the info.
I am using th following code in onPostExecute():

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Dashboard.class  );
    ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

But it jumps to another Activity then after a few seconds opens the next Activity.

Second issue I am having is carrying along an image with all the other information into DB. I have a URI I obtained from retreiving the image from device. Now from my research I know this URI has to be turned into bitmap, which in turn has to become Base64, am I right? can I just send the URI as it is? I am trying to use the DB Background Task to also format the URI, I have tried using another background task but I must have done something wrong.

I am trying to insert without image for now and I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error, it points to a line in the Background Task where I have one of the params to send into the DB. Is there a limit on the number of params that can be set?

Background task:

```
package name;
import statements;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
//Constructor needed to pass info into the BackgroundTask
Context ctx;
BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //from this method pass info into MySQL DB
    String reg_url = "http://ipaddress/folder/phpscript.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if (method.equals("register")){
        String fname = params[1];
        String lname = params[2];
        String age = params[3];
        String mobnum = params[4];
        String homenum = params[5];
        String email = params[6];
        String city = params[7];
        String country = params[8];
        String gender = params[9];
        String dob = params[10];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(fname,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("lname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(lname,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("age","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(age,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("mobnum","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(mobnum,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("homenum","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(homenum,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("city","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(city,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("country","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(country,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("gender","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(gender,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("dob","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(dob,"UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            return "Registration success...";

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Dashboard.class  );
    ctx.startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

Activity using the Background Task(button uses android:onClick to call the method):

```
public void userReg(View view){
//initialise variables by retreiving user input
    fname = ET_fname.getText().toString();
    lname = ET_lname.getText().toString();
    mobnum = ET_mobnum.getText().toString();
    homenum = ET_homenum.getText().toString();
    email =ET_email.getText().toString();
    city = ET_city.getText().toString();
    country = ET_country.getText().toString();
    gender = ET_gender.getText().toString();

    //pass info into the BackgroundTask
    String method ="register";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method, fname, lname, String.valueOf(age), mobnum, homenum, email, city, country, gender, dob);
    finish();
}
```

Basically I want to be able to insert info as well as the image into the DB.

PHP webservice:

```
<?php

require "init.php";

$fname=$_POST["user"];
$lname=$_POST["lname"];
$age=$_POST["age"];
$mobnum=$_POST["mobnum"];
$hnum=$_POST["homenum"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$city=$_POST["city"];
$country=$_POST["country"];
$gender=$_POST["gender"];
$dob=$_POST["dob"];

$sql_query="insert into teacher_information values('$fname','$lname','$age','$mobnum','$hnum','$email','$city','$country','$gender', '$dob');";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, You can call the activity in the method `onPostExecute()`.
Send the previous context by constructor. 
Then use the following code in the method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(cotenxt, NextActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

**Secondly**,
Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21306831/831127) to upload image to php service.

Comment: I have edited my post.. I am trying to input info without image. one of the fields in the DB is Autoincrement, so i am not feeding in data for that. just the others obtained from the user.

Comment: I am testing on a real device, and trying to connect to MySQL on WAMP. According to the other posts, I have used the ip for my phone, but it just jumps to the next activity without insertin into DB. Any suggestions? @Abdulhamid Dhaiban